# How to remove duplicate elements from array based on condition?

Tags: javascript, arrays, ecmascript-6

Trying to write logic if there are multiple messages and element  `settlementDesc` does not contain not Covered or invalid quantity and vice versa. i should be able to remove duplicate with notCovered/invalidQuantity string and keep.

data

```
All these scenarios should be if messages are more then 1 in length 
Scenario#1 

    const messages = [

              {

                "settlementCode": "58",

                "settlementDesc": "Not Covered Needs prior authorization: System could not process your request. Call us at the toll-free number on your benefit ID card."

              },

              {

                "settlementCode": "58",

                "settlementDesc": "Not Covered Needs prior authorization: System could not process your request. Call us at the toll-free number on your benefit ID card."

              },

              {

                "settlementCode": "359",

                "settlementDesc": "Needs prior authorization: System could not process your request. Call us at the toll-free number on your benefit ID card."

              }

            ];

Scenario#2 

 const messages = [

              {

                "settlementCode": "58",

                "settlementDesc": "Not Covered Needs prior authorization: System could not process your request. Call us at the toll-free number on your benefit ID card."

              },

              {

                "settlementCode": "58",

                "settlementDesc": "Not Covered Needs prior authorization: System could not process your request. Call us at the toll-free number on your benefit ID card."

              }

            ];
```

main.js

```
const validateEntries = (messages) => {
  let filteredMsg;
  if (!messages) {
    return [];
  }
if(messages.length > 1) {
  console.log("Multiple messages");
  const response = [];
  let bRet = false;
  const mulitpleMessages = messages.reduce((acc,curr) => {
    if (/not covered|invalid quantity/i.test(curr.settlementDesc !== true) {
      bRet = true;
    }
    if(bRet) {
      if( acc.settlementCode == curr.settlementCode) {
        return acc;
      }
    }
    return curr;
  });
  filteredMsg = mulitpleMessages;
} else {
  filteredMsg = messages.filter((item) => {
    if (/not covered|invalid quantity/i.test(item.settlementDesc)) {
      return true;
    } else {
      return item.settlementDesc.includes(':');
    }
  });
}

  return filteredMsg;
};

console.log(validateEntries(messages));
```

expected Ouput

```
Scneario#1 ouput 

    [


                  {

                    "settlementCode": "359",

                    "settlementDesc": "Needs prior authorization: System could not process your request. Call us at the toll-free number on your benefit ID card."

                  }

                ];

Scenario#2 

[

              {

                "settlementCode": "58",

                "settlementDesc": "Not Covered Needs prior authorization: System could not process your request. Call us at the toll-free number on your benefit ID card."

              }]
```

Error

```
let bRet = false;
  38 |   const mulitpleMessages = messages.reduce((acc,curr) => {
> 39 |     if (/not covered|invalid quantity/i.test(curr.settlementDesc !== true) {
     |                                                                           
  41 |       bRet = true;
  42 |     }
```

Comment: The item will be considered duplicate on the basis of `settlementCode` or `settlementDesc` or both needs to be same.

Comment: @Maheer Ali duplicate will be consider on `settlementCode`

Comment: remove your object on the basis of settlementCode it will be safe.

Answer (score 1):

You can use nested `filter()`

```js
const messages = [ { "settlementCode": "58", "settlementDesc": "Not Covered Needs prior authorization: System could not process your request. Call us at the toll-free number on your benefit ID card." }, { "settlementCode": "58", "settlementDesc": "Not Covered Needs prior authorization: System could not process your request. Call us at the toll-free number on your benefit ID card." }, { "settlementCode": "359", "settlementDesc": "Needs prior authorization: System could not process your request. Call us at the toll-free number on your benefit ID card." } ];

const res = messages.filter(x => 
               messages.filter(a => a.settlementCode === x.settlementCode).length === 1
            );

console.log(res)
```

Comment: got confused writing question my logic has two scenarios 1# if there are duplicate keep only one 2#  if there are elements that are without notCovered/invalidQuantity then delete all the elements that contains notCovered/invalidQuantity

Comment: your answer can solve scenario #2 , how we can tweak for scenario #1, in this scenario all elements could have same code

Comment: @hussain Your example is not sufficient to describe your problem. Update the example with adding and two items from which one of them will remain.

Answer (score 0):

you're just missing a closing parenthesis at this line:

```
if (/not covered|invalid quantity/i.test(curr.settlementDesc !== true) {
```

fix it like this:

```
const messages = [
    {
      "settlementCode": "58",
      "settlementDesc": "Not Covered Needs prior authorization: System could not process your request. Call us at the toll-free number on your benefit ID card."
    },
    {
      "settlementCode": "58",
      "settlementDesc": "Not Covered Needs prior authorization: System could not process your request. Call us at the toll-free number on your benefit ID card."
    },
    {
      "settlementCode": "359",
      "settlementDesc": "Needs prior authorization: System could not process your request. Call us at the toll-free number on your benefit ID card."
    }
  ];

  const validateEntries = (messages) => {
    let filteredMsg;
    if (!messages) {
      return [];
    }
  if(messages.length > 1) {
    console.log("Multiple messages");
    const response = [];
    let bRet = false;
    const mulitpleMessages = messages.reduce((acc,curr) => {
      if (/not covered|invalid quantity/i.test(curr.settlementDesc !== true)) {
        bRet = true;
      }
      if(bRet) {
        if( acc.settlementCode == curr.settlementCode) {
          return acc;
        }
      }
      return curr;
    });
    filteredMsg = mulitpleMessages;
  } else {
    filteredMsg = messages.filter((item) => {
      if (/not covered|invalid quantity/i.test(item.settlementDesc)) {
        return true;
      } else {
        return item.settlementDesc.includes(':');
      }
    });
  }

    return filteredMsg;
  };

  console.log(validateEntries(messages));
```

your code is working fine

Answer (score 0):

It strikes me that this is calling out for some cleaner, better-factored code.  I'm imagining a solution that looks something like this:

```js
const transform = combine (
  uniqueBy (sameProp ('settlementCode') ),
  filter (not (propMatches ('settlementDesc', ['not covered', 'invalid quantity'])))
)
```

What will all those helper functions do?

The idea is that `combine` would take two functions, and return a new one that passes the output of one into the other.  There is a standard name for this, `compose`, so that's what I would actually choose.

`sameProp('foo')` would accept two objects and tell whether they had equal `foo` properties.  So `sameProp` would accept a property name and return that binary predicate.  (A predicate is just a function that returns `true` or `false`)

`uniqueBy` would take a binary predicate and a list, and remove any duplicates based on that predicate, keeping only the first one.

`filter` would simply elevate `Array.prototype.filter` into a standalone function.

`propMatches` would accept a property name and a list of strings, returning a function that accepts an object and reporting whether the names property of that object is a regex match for one of those strings.

And finally, `not` would simply accept a predicate and return a second one that returns `false` if the initial one returns `true` and `true` if it returns `false`.  (It might alternatively be called `invert`, `opposite`, or `complement`.)

Here is an implementation of that:

```js
const compose = (f, g) => 
  (x) => f(g(x))
  
const filter = (fn) => (xs) => 
  xs.filter(fn)

const not = (f) =>
  (x) => !f(x)

const sameProp = (prop) => (a, b) => 
  a [prop] === b [prop]

const uniqueBy = (pred) => (xs) =>
  xs .filter ( (x, i) => xs .findIndex (y => pred (x, y) ) == i )

const propMatches = (prop, vals, re = new RegExp (vals .join ('|'), 'i') ) =>
  (x) => !! re .test ( x [prop] )

const transform = compose (
  uniqueBy (sameProp ('settlementCode')),
  filter (not (propMatches ('settlementDesc', ['not covered', 'invalid quantity'])))
)

const messages = [{settlementCode: "58", settlementDesc: "Not Covered Needs prior authorization: System could not process your request. Call us at the toll-free number on your benefit ID card."}, {  settlementCode: "58", settlementDesc: "Not Covered Needs prior authorization: System could not process your request. Call us at the toll-free number on your benefit ID card."}, {  settlementCode: "359", settlementDesc: "Needs prior authorization: System could not process your request. Call us at the toll-free number on your benefit ID card."}]

console .log (
  transform (messages)
)
```

Note that the helper functions, especially the first four, are extremely simple functions.  They are all (except maybe `propMatches`) code that is likely reusable across many parts of an application.  So they can be housed in your internal utility library, leaving only `transform` (and again, possibly `propMatches`) as part of the implementation of this requirement.

There are other things you might want to do with them.  We can easily imagine a version of `compose` which takes any number of functions, or one that takes them in the opposite order.  We could also imagine that we might want to pass more that one parameter into the function that results from it.  But we can add such enhancements later, when we actually need them.

Alternately, we can use a utility library that supplies such functions.  I'm one of the authors of [Ramda](https://ramdajs.com), and that library supplies (an expanded) [`compose`](https://ramdajs.com/docs/#compose), a version of `sameProp` called [`eqProps`](https://ramdajs.com/docs/#eqProps), a slightly differently-spelled [`uniqBy`](https://ramdajs.com/docs/#uniqB), [`filter`](https://ramdajs.com/docs/#filter), and a version of `not` called [`complement`](https://ramdajs.com/docs/#complement).  For me, having these useful functions always available makes much of my coding significantly simpler.